# How to get gmail inbox feed from a nested label

Tags: gmail, feed, atom-feed, inbox

As specified here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed, I can get a feed of unread emails under a label 'work' by simply calling https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/work/

But what to do in case I have nested labels?
i.e. in case I have a label named 'Important' nested under 'Work'

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me how did you parse the xml data from inbox feed to json ? or

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to replace all slashes with dashes:

If your nested label is Work/Unpleasant the url is:

```
https://<user>:<pw>@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/Work-Unpleasant
```